# Angular Cookie SessionId

Tags: angular, cookies

Im using ngx-cookie-service to read cookies.
It works well but unfortunally it seems like it can't read session's cookies.

In this picture you can see stored cookies:

[image]

In this other picture, you can see how the library returns only the csrftoken cookie (the only one that is not a session cookies):

[image]

The requests to backend are correctly authenticated but I'd like to know in frontend if sessionid is stored. Otherwise I need to make a call to backend to know if user is correctly logged and often Django Backend return me as Anonymous User when not authenticated. I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Searching around I found that that kind of cookie are called HTTPOnly cookie so client/frontend cant access them.